# parse exception while converting string with timezone to date

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to parse a string with a time zone into a date format, how can I accomplish this?

I am using the code below, but I am getting a parse exception. What I am trying to do is getting the date in UTC time zone, irrespecitve of the time zone I get in the input string. **Below is the code:**

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String DIA_TIME1="201307111611400";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssz");
        Date testdate=sdf1.parse(DIA_TIME1);
        System.out.println("Current System Time is: " + testdate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both String date and format, for your date try:

```
String DIA_TIME1="20130711161140-0000";
```

and for the string format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ");
```

the last one is upper case Z.

Or, if ois not your intention to have a time zone, you have a spare 0 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (your date does not contain timezone, it seems that you have milliseconds):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
```